# Python: mask array, process subarrays and concatenate the results together following original ordering

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is my working example. I either check whether at least one entry of the events is 1 or only the first entry is 1 depending on whether the id exists.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"id": [None, 'a', None, 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

events = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]).T

# expectations to be either aggressive or normal
# 1 - no id and event2
# 0 - no events
# 1 - no id and event2 and event3
# 1 - id but event1 
# 0 - id thus event2 neglected
# 0 - id thus event3 neglected
# 0 - id thus event2 and event 3 neglected

mask = data['id'].notna()

result = np.zeros(len(data))
result[mask]  = events[mask].T[0].astype(float)
result[~mask] = np.any(events[~mask], axis=1).astype(float)
```

it returns `array([1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])` as expected.

I am asking myself, whether there is a more elegant and / or also more performant way to achieve the same.

A list comprehension would be a one liner, but I assume it would be slower (?)

edit: `arr = events`. I wanted to make a better naming

logic:

```
if id != None, return the first bit of the events array 
else check whether at least one bit of the events array is 1
```

Comment: what is `arr` in your code? `events`?

Comment: Can you also clarify the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear but it looks like you could simplify to:

```
result = (data['id'].notna().to_numpy() == events[:, 0].astype(bool)).astype(int)
```

Alternatively, using your original code and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
result = np.where(data['id'].notna(),
                  events[:, 0],
                  np.any(events, axis=1)).astype(float)
```

Output: `array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])`